# mysql vs mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Подскажите пожалуйста какие недостатки\преимущества mongodb над mysql и наоборот.

Стоит ли mongodb использовать для больших проектов, со связями тд.

Читал что пока идет запись в монгу, то ее нельзя читать, то есть если много запросов на запись, то она не актуальна. Правильно я понимаю ?

Mysql я знаю хорошо, но монго подкупает меня тем что у нее нету точной структуры, и ее легко расширять и изменять.

Спасибо за ответы !

Comment: Вы не стой стороны подходите к вопросу. Важна структура данных. Если ваши данные удобно хранить в документарном виде - NoSQL решения. Если данные по природе своей лучше организуются в реляционную структуру - SQL. Ну или использовать две БД каждую для своего типа данных

Answer (score 2):

Вы  спрашиваете о разных семействах БД. 
Многие совмещают в проектах как реляционные БД так и NoSQL решения. 
Было бы правильно спрашивать MySQL или PostgreSQL. 
Касаемо блокировки почитайте https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/faq/concurrency/ .
При выборе решения не забудьте что у MongoDB нет привычных join. Также синтаксис javascript

Comment: то есть монго использовать для данных которые читаются, к примеру, товары, а для заказов и платежей уже mysql, тк там есть транзакции и innodb отлично подходит для записи и чтения ?

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy нет, разница именно в оптимальной для БД структуре данных и формах связи между ними.